# Display Gujarati Language in Webview in android

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-widget

I want to build application for display story where **storyname** and **storycontent** should be display in gujarati language.

i have used **Shruti.ttf** font

For **storyname** i have used textview and for **storycontent** i have used webview

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "shruti.ttf");
poetryTitleText.setTypeface(font);
poetryTitleText.setText("Snow White");
```

and it works very well.

But to show **storycontent** in webview i have used HTML Page and set font name in `<style>` tag of HTML. but it shows square icon.

emulator wont show font in gujarati language. even i am sending gujarati string from **R.string** file.

Help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey if you found solution then please help me i have same problem..

Answer (score 0):

-I found 2 solutions for you i am not sure about useful or not but you can try it

1.)Use Textview instead webview

```
Html.fromHtml(username + " shared "
                    + "<font color=\"#47C4E3\">" + objnews.news_title
                    + "</font>");
```

-Set this code to Textview.settext(..above code..)

2.)Set jeader of webview using this **code**:-

`Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
headers.put("Accept-Language", "Your fonts");
mWebView.loadUrl("http://developer.android.com", headers);`

-THanks! Please tell me if this is the right path you wanted or not?